# Primefaces datatable column headers not being resized to match row data column size

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Using Primefaces 5.1, I have set my p:datatable element attributes as follows:

```
resizableColumns="true"
scrollable="true"
scrollWidth="100%"
```

When I put the data in my data table, each column automatically resizes to accommodate its longest value, but the column headers do not resize, and thus are unaligned (border-wise) with the data below them.

I saw many posts that were similar to this, but I did not see one that offered a solution I could get to work, and I tried a bunch of them.  If anyone can enlighten me about how to make the column headers resize in concert with the table data, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Tried PF5.2? And btw,`h:dataTable` is NOT PrimeFaces…  typo?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, sorry.  I have corrected it.  I am going to try 5.2 today.  Unfortunately, I am in an odd situation where my development system does not have an internet connection, so I must bring things in from the outside.

Comment: I'm also having this issue with Primefaces 5.1. Did you find a fix, or did 5.2 work for you?